# Употребление предлогов С и ИЗ

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Правильно ли говорить - человек пришёл с сайта? Если у сайта есть название, например Цветочек, то можно ли сказать - человек пришёл с Цветочка?

Comment: Как Вы объясняете фразу «человек пришёл с (из) сайта»? Что значит пришёл?

Answer (score 2):

Ну да, правильно.

И правило прозрачнейшее:

если движение *на,* то возвращение будет *с;*

если *в,* то *из*.

Зашёл на сайт, пришёл с сайта; зашёл на "Цветочек" (как синоним и имя сайта), пришёл с "Цветочка";

букашка заползла в цветочек - выкарабкалась из цветочка.